# Are envirnoment variables part of the kernel space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have been searching this question for hours but can not find a simple yes or no answer (or maybe depends on OS or architecture), which is what I am looking for. This probably might be a very trivial question.

My hunch is that environment variables of a process are in the kernel space and hence are kernel data structures and live right above the process image in the virtual address space.

Comment: No. They are stored in the regular data space of the process. This is why there is no way for a process to change the environment variables of its parent, but can pass modified environment variables to its children. On Linux, you even get a pointer to them as the third argument of `main()`. And the sentence "kernel data structures live right above the process image in the virtual address space" is meaningless; virtual address space is virtual.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know its meaningless in the physical sense, which is why I wrote virtually address space, i.e., how the process sees the addresses before they are translated to physical addresses (through paging) and are send on the address bus.

Comment: The point is that the virtual address space is virtual. There is no relationship between virtual addresses and physical addresses. Consider an array `int x[100]`; now,  `x + 5` is a virtual address lower than `x + 55`, but the corresponding physical address of of `x + 5` may be higher than the corresponding physical address of `x + 55`, and it may be that one or both of them don't even have a corresponding physical address.

Comment: "There is no relationship between virtual addresses and physcial addresses" . I get what you mean, but if I remember correctly, the translation from virtual --> physical are kept track of in page directories by the kernel.

Comment: Yes, there is a page table. What I mean is that a virtual page may or may not be mapped to a physical page, and even if two virtual pages are both mapped it is not necessary that the order relationship be preserved.

Comment: "It is not necessary that the order relationship be preserved" well that is what you should have said from the start. I am probably being a bit pedantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you think the environment is stored in the kernel?

That would require a dedicated syscall to export it OR a shared memory area mapped into the process. But the process can modify it's own environment, so what happens now? It is trivial to check that the environment is initially stored on the stack alongside argv.

Similarly, why would you google around instead of checking the implementation. For instance, there is /proc/PID/environ and checking that clearly shows it is being read from the target process' address space. http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/fs/proc/base.c#L908